# Add StatusBar Plugin to my IonicApp doesn't works

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I would use the StatusBar plugin in my Ionic (Cordova + AngularJS) app.

I tried `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar` seen [on ng-cordova page](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/statusbar/) and [github(https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar), but in my cmd appears a "Error: 404 Not Found".

This is the error:

```
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-statusbar
Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-statusbar
at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:268:14)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:876:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:827:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Is it a my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar` try below command line

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```